# Как поместить RadioButton'ы, созданые в fxml файле, в ToggleGroup непосредственно через java файл

Tags: javafx, radiobutton

Я создал 3 объекта RadioButton(с помощью Scene Builder). При попытке создать ToggleGroup и поместить поместить туда эти кнопки, они ведут себя, как будто не находятся в одной ToggleGroup: я могу выбрать несколько кнопок одновременно

Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чём моя ошибка.
P.S. Я новичок

```
package application;

import javafx.fxml.FXML;

import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;

import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;

public class SampleController {

    @FXML
    private RadioButton radioButton1;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton radioButton2;

    @FXML
    private RadioButton radioButton3;

    void inizializate() {
        ToggleGroup group = new ToggleGroup();
        radioButton1.setToggleGroup(group);
        radioButton2.setToggleGroup(group);
        radioButton3.setToggleGroup(group);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А, так метод должен называть `initialize()`, а не `inizializate()`. В английском языке даже слова такого нет.

Вот такой код у меня работает:

```
package sample;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.RadioButton;
import javafx.scene.control.ToggleGroup;
public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private RadioButton R1;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton R2;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton R3;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton R4;
    @FXML
    void initialize() {
        ToggleGroup tg = new ToggleGroup();
        R1.setToggleGroup(tg);
        R2.setToggleGroup(tg);
        R3.setToggleGroup(tg);
        R4.setToggleGroup(tg);

    }
}
```

Comment: Я поменял. Тоже самое

Comment: Тогда попробуйте перед этим дописать @FXML

Comment: Дописал. Не помогает. Я понимаю, что это не необходимость, но всё-таки

Comment: Хмм... Даже не знаю в чем может быть ошибка... А код я так понимаю никаких ошибок не выдает? Добавил в вопрос мой код, который прекрасно работает. Может есть какие-то проблемы с самым fxml файлом? А может все же где-то опечатка в названии метода..

Comment: Да, ошибок нет. Всё запускается, только выглядит так, как на скрине. Вы говорите, что у вас при запуске кнопки ведут, как и должны себя вести в одной ToggleGroup?

Comment: Да,  при включении одной выключаются другие

Comment: Перезапускал несколько раз эклипс - не помогало. Я удалил тот Java FX проект, предварительно скопировав из него код, создал новый проэкт, вставил код, и всё заработало.

Comment: Как думаете с чем это может быть связано? Уже не первый раз приходится перезапускать эклипс или же вовсе создавать новый проэкт

Comment: Наверное глупо говорить про сбои в системе, так как все ошибки - это, конечно, ошибки разработчиков, в той или иной мере, естественно. Однако я не могу даже представить, почему могло не работать. Может вы куда-то не туда кликнули при создании, может ужалили что, может файл какой между папками перетащили и даже не заметили, может в ScenwBuilder ошибки, т. е. ошибка в fxml файле была. Кстати, если бы вы не справились, то у меня была идея, которую уже собирался посоветовать: создать новый проект с моим кодом и постепенно заменять на ваш. Так найти ошибку

Comment: Кстати, в вашем новом проекте метод вы как назвали? Initialize? А ваш inizializate подходит? Был ли я в итоге прав как минимум насчет названия метода? Работает ли с "неверным" названием?

Comment: Да! Всё-таки всё из-за этого! Спасибо!

Comment: Из-за чего? Из-за initialize? Вы же говорили, что пробовали и не сработало...

Comment: Тогда не сработало. Видимо я чего-то начудил... А вы не знаете, я могу сделать, чтобы файл обращался не к методу "initialize" как к основному, а к другому, например "main", если таковой присутствует в файле. То есть сменить имя основного метода.

Comment: Погодите. Во-первых, вот СЕЙЧАС, когда у вас работает с методом initialize работает ли у вас с методом inizializate? Если это было как минимум одной из ошибок, то я бы попросил вас принять мой ответ, если же проблема была вообще не в этом, то настаивать на принятии ответа я, конечно, не буду (но не против). Во-вторых, я понятия не имею можно ли сделать как вы сказали, потому что не представляю зачем? Мне это никогда не было нужно, так что я даже не пытался.

Comment: Я принял ответ, спасибо. У меня там новый вопрос появился. Посмотрите, вдруг знаете